# Join two MySQL tables where the content of a tableA.column is the name of the desired tableB.column

Tags: mysql, join

Table A:

```
mac.............date........area........value<br>
222222222222    2018-10-16  area0001    123<br>
222222222222    2018-10-16  area0002    167<br>
555555555555    2018-10-16  area0001    231<br>
555555555555    2018-10-16  area0002    187<br>
```

Table B:

```
mac.............area0001.....area0002....area0003<br> 
222222222222    Apt-101      Apt-102     Apt-103<br>
555555555555    apt-104      Apt-105     Apt-106<br>
```

I need, for date=2018-10-16:

```
area.......value<br>
Apt-101    123<br>
Apt-102    167<br>
Apt-104    231<br>
Apt-105    187<br>
```

Thanks in Advance
Paulo Borges

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using `union`

```
select t2.area0001 as area,t1.value from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.mac=t2.mac
union
select t2.area0002,t1.value from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.mac=t2.mac
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried that but got something other than expected, only Apt-101 comes on the result and values belonging to Apt-102 come as Apt-101. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The condition above was too complex for the required task and I decided to change the way data was stored.

Putting data of interest as a field name was not anticipated to be such a problem. 
Now area0001, area0002, area000x on TableB are no longer field names and became content under a field name "area" and Apt-101, Apt-102, Apt-10x under a field name of "label".

Problem solved.

Thanks 
Paulo